# Android to MYSQL thru php

Tags: php, android, mysql

Hi i am follwing this tutorial over here http://fahmirahman.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/connection-between-php-server-and-android-client-using-http-and-json  and unable to get the desired results as expected, this is the food.php file that i have at my website [techiequickie.com/food.php](http://techiequickie.com/food.php)

then this is the code that i am trying to put in my andorid main.java file

```
    package com.connectsql.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.ParseException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ConnectsqlActivity extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);



        String result = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        StringBuilder sb=null;



        //http post
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://techiequickie.com/food.php");
            List<? extends NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = null;
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        }


        //convert response to string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
            String line="0";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }

        //paring data
        int fd_id;
        String fd_name;
        try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject json_data=null;

        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                fd_id=json_data.getInt("FOOD_ID");
                fd_name=json_data.getString("FOOD_NAME");
        }

        }catch(JSONException e1){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Food Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch (ParseException e1){
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

the error i am getting is application closed unexpectedly, so i donot understand what i have to do to get this work tks by the way my main.xml is default as in i did not add any controls there.
below is my main.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.82"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

tks

LOGCAT error

```
01-30 16:07:12.155: D/AndroidRuntime(787): Shutting down VM
01-30 16:07:12.155: W/dalvikvm(787): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-30 16:07:12.175: E/AndroidRuntime(787): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-30 16:07:12.175: E/AndroidRuntime(787): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.connectsql.test/com.connectsql.test.ConnectsqlActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
01-30 16:07:12.175: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-30 16:07:12.175: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-30 16:07:12.175: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-30 16:07:12.175: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-30 16:07:12.175: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-30 16:07:12.175: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-30 16:07:12.175: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-30 16:07:12.175: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-30 16:07:12.175: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-30 16:07:12.175: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-30 16:07:12.175: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-30 16:07:12.175: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-30 16:07:12.175: E/AndroidRuntime(787): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
01-30 16:07:12.175: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
01-30 16:07:12.175: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:210)
01-30 16:07:12.175: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
01-30 16:07:12.175: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at com.connectsql.test.ConnectsqlActivity.onCreate(ConnectsqlActivity.java:30)
01-30 16:07:12.175: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-30 16:07:12.175: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-30 16:07:12.175: E/AndroidRuntime(787):  ... 11 more
```

**@Sergey logcat error** please take note that my modified main.xml code is below

```
01-31 00:39:20.625: E/log_tag(424): Error in http connectionjava.net.UnknownHostException: techiequickie.com
01-31 00:39:20.625: E/log_tag(424): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 00:39:20.625: D/AndroidRuntime(424): Shutting down VM
01-31 00:39:20.625: W/dalvikvm(424): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-31 00:39:20.665: E/AndroidRuntime(424): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 00:39:20.665: E/AndroidRuntime(424): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mysql/com.mysql.MysqlconActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 00:39:20.665: E/AndroidRuntime(424):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-31 00:39:20.665: E/AndroidRuntime(424):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-31 00:39:20.665: E/AndroidRuntime(424):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-31 00:39:20.665: E/AndroidRuntime(424):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-31 00:39:20.665: E/AndroidRuntime(424):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-31 00:39:20.665: E/AndroidRuntime(424):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-31 00:39:20.665: E/AndroidRuntime(424):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-31 00:39:20.665: E/AndroidRuntime(424):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 00:39:20.665: E/AndroidRuntime(424):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-31 00:39:20.665: E/AndroidRuntime(424):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-31 00:39:20.665: E/AndroidRuntime(424):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-31 00:39:20.665: E/AndroidRuntime(424):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-31 00:39:20.665: E/AndroidRuntime(424): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 00:39:20.665: E/AndroidRuntime(424):  at com.android.internal.os.LoggingPrintStream.println(LoggingPrintStream.java:298)
01-31 00:39:20.665: E/AndroidRuntime(424):  at com.mysql.MysqlconActivity.onCreate(MysqlconActivity.java:66)
01-31 00:39:20.665: E/AndroidRuntime(424):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-31 00:39:20.665: E/AndroidRuntime(424):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-31 00:39:20.665: E/AndroidRuntime(424):  ... 11 more
01-31 00:39:28.775: I/Process(424): Sending signal. PID: 424 SIG: 9
01-31 00:43:37.995: E/log_tag(473): Error in http connectionjava.net.UnknownHostException: techiequickie.com
01-31 00:43:37.995: E/log_tag(473): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 00:43:37.995: D/AndroidRuntime(473): Shutting down VM
01-31 00:43:37.995: W/dalvikvm(473): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
01-31 00:43:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(473): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-31 00:43:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(473): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mysql/com.mysql.MysqlconActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 00:43:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-31 00:43:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-31 00:43:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-31 00:43:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-31 00:43:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-31 00:43:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-31 00:43:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-31 00:43:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-31 00:43:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-31 00:43:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-31 00:43:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-31 00:43:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-31 00:43:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(473): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-31 00:43:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at com.android.internal.os.LoggingPrintStream.println(LoggingPrintStream.java:298)
01-31 00:43:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at com.mysql.MysqlconActivity.onCreate(MysqlconActivity.java:61)
01-31 00:43:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-31 00:43:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-31 00:43:38.036: E/AndroidRuntime(473):  ... 11 more
```

Modified main.xml, i attached a screenshot below because i added  the listview and from your code the last line you refer to the test_text field saying that "tv.setText(fd_id+" "+fd_name);" but trying to understand this line.tks for all the effort.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This error doesnt have anything to do with PHP, the relevant part is just `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'`

Comment: FYI, the newer versions of the SDK do not permit any network connection tasks on the UI thread (it will throw an exception). You MUST do any network based tasks as an AsyncTask to keep the UI from freezing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must add the following to your layout because you are extending ListActivity

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             />
```

otherwise it's okay I'd use HttpGet though in this sample.

EDIT:
layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello" />

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                />

</LinearLayout>
```

code:

```
import org.apache.http.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;

import android.widget.TextView;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ConnectsqlActivity extends ListActivity {

       @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String result = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        StringBuilder sb=null;

        try{
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        //    setProxy(httpclient,"yourproxyorIP",9090,"username","password"); //use your proxy's port

            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("http://techiequickie.com/food.php");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        }
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
            String line="0";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }
        System.out.println(result);
        //paring data
        int fd_id=0;
        String fd_name=null;
        try{
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject json_data=null;

        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                fd_id=json_data.getInt("FOOD_ID");
                fd_name=json_data.getString("FOOD_NAME");
        }

        }catch(JSONException e1){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Food Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch (ParseException e1){
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.test);
        TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test_text);
        tv.setText(fd_id+" "+fd_name);

    }

private static void setProxy (DefaultHttpClient httpClient,
                String proxy,int port,String username,String password)
{
    HttpParams params = httpClient.getParams();
    params.setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY,
            new HttpHost( proxy,port));
    if(username!=null&&password!=null){
    httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(proxy, port),
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password)
        );
    }
    httpClient.setParams(params);
}


}
```

Comment: hi Sergey i realised the silly mistake and i just tried your answer but still getting the same error when i try to run the code, i have made all the changes that you have asked me to, i have posted the outcome of logcat for your code back in my question on top, please take a look.

Comment: I ran the code and it worked perfectly. Did you add the ListView to your layout with the ID  `<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                />`

Comment: by the way this is a different project name as i put in different computer, does that make any difference?

Comment: one thing i noticed in the catlog was that caused by java.lang.NullpointerException rather than the previous error which was due to the lack of listview in the layout..

Comment: you just use the ConnectsqlActivity in your manifest file to call it from there and yes MysqlconActivity is a wrong name looking at your exception if you want to use the code I pasted.

Comment: your emulator or phone cannot resolve the host `Error in http connectionjava.net.UnknownHostException: techiequickie.com`

Comment: how do i go about doing that and also please enlighten me on how to do that? tks

Comment: once again. your emulator could not resolve the host techiequickie.com so your Manifest doesn't seem to be the problem. see if your emulator has the connection to internet and can do stuff.

Comment: just to let you know i am trying to figure out how to grant network access to the AVD..a few moments please

Comment: set the following permissions into your   AndroidManifest.xml file  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: hi sergey i am trying to grant acces to my AVD using this command is this way correct, i am using a proxy at my workplace,' -http-proxy http://jackboi:abc123@:IMCELESTIX01.xxx.xxxx.com:8080'

Comment: haha guess what? it is working i mean there is no crash or force close now, but just that not able to access the internet. the application opens up and doesnot display anything. Tks so much but can u pls verify if the above comment code is valid?

Comment: i have updated the code with the setProxy function you may want to look at it too and check if it works in your environment.

Comment: hi sergey i will try this at home and let you know i am still getting the forceclose exception once in a while but i know what might be wrong, but happy with this so far,  but please do take a look when later on i run in to difficulty or if i encounter any issue tks so much!